# How to remove bottom line of Header and top line of Footer in Native Base?

Tags: react-native, native-base

[as the image can show it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pjQOK.png) , my app shows a line at the top of my Footer and at the bottom of my Header. Its seems a common thing in Native Base. I have checked out the native-base theme but I can´t find some to fix this error.

Code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Container, Content, Footer, FooterTab, Button, Icon, Text, Header, Title, Left, Right, Body, } from 'native-base';
export default class FooterTabsExample extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
          <Container>
              <Header>
                <Left>
                    <Button transparent>
                        <Icon name='arrow-back' />
                    </Button>
                </Left>
                <Body>
                    <Title>Header</Title>
                </Body>
                <Right>
                    <Button transparent>
                        <Icon name='menu' />
                    </Button>
                </Right>
              </Header>
              <Content style={{backgroundColor:'black'}}/>

              <Footer >
                  <FooterTab>
                      <Button>
                          <Icon name="apps" />
                          <Text>Apps</Text>
                      </Button>
                      <Button>
                          <Icon name="camera" />
                          <Text>Camera</Text>
                      </Button>
                      <Button active>
                          <Icon active name="navigate" />
                          <Text>Navigate</Text>
                      </Button>
                      <Button>
                          <Icon name="person" />
                          <Text>Contact</Text>
                      </Button>
                  </FooterTab>
              </Footer>
          </Container>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: For the header you can add noShadow. E.g. <Header noShadow>, for the footer, I haven't found something similar.

Answer (score 12):

Just override the `borderBottomWidth` for `Header` and `borderTopWidth` for `Footer`:

```
<Header style={{borderBottomWidth: 0}}>
  ...
</Header>

...

<Footer style={{borderTopWidth: 0}}>
  ...
</Footer>
```

Answer (score 6):

```
<Header style={{borderBottomWidth: 0, shadowOffset: {height: 0, width: 0}, 
shadowOpacity: 0, elevation: 0}}>
```

This worked for me. If you're using Android you must add elevation: 0.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to set border color which you are using in the header or footer background.

```
<Header style={{
        backgroundColor:'#141414',
        borderColor: "#141414",

    }}></Header>
```

Answer (score 1):

The top answer doesn't work for android as you also need: `elevation:0`

So @ap003's answer is more complete.

This worked for me for footer on android:

```
<Footer style = {{borderTopWidth: 0, elevation: 0,}} />
```

You can use the same logic for header (replace borderTopWidth with borderBottomWidth)

...

Sorry for separate comment as I'm unable to comment on existing posts (new user huhu).

Answer (score 1):

Just use following style to remove bottom border line.

```
<Header style = {{elevation: 0}} />
```

Answer (score 1):

For React Navigation v5 add `shadowColor: 'transparent'` in 'headerStyle' in the `options props`.