# how to change the active footertab background color in nativebase

Tags: react-native, footer, react-native-ios, native-base

I want to change the background color of my active footer tab in native base. I haven't found anything on that o the official doc. Pls, guide me on this. Thanks

```
<Footer style={styles.footer}>
    <FooterTab  style={styles.footerTab} >
      <TouchableOpacity

        onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('Mainhome')}>
        <Image
          source={require('../assets/home.png')}
          style={styles.footerIcon}
        />
      </TouchableOpacity>

      <TouchableOpacity

        onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('Search')}>
        <Image
          source={require('../assets/search.png')}
          style={styles.footerIcon}
        />
      </TouchableOpacity>
      <TouchableOpacity
</FooterTab>
<Footer>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside tab bar you can use your component and to make its color change you need to pass active props by default the active color is blue ... and to change it just add color to the component inside fotter tab 
Working example: https://snack.expo.io/@msbot01/authentic-chips

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Text, View, StyleSheet, ScrollView, FlatList } from 'react-native';
import { Container, Header, Content, Footer, FooterTab, Button} from 'native-base';


export default class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {

      tabStatus1:true,
      tabStatus2:false,
      tabStatus3:false,
      tabStatus4:false,
    }
  }

  componentDidMount(){


  }

  checkTabSelected(tab){
    switch(tab) {
      case 1:
        this.setState({

          tabStatus1:true,
          tabStatus2:false,
          tabStatus3:false,
          tabStatus4:false
        })
        // code block
        break;
      case 2:
        this.setState({

          tabStatus1:false,
          tabStatus2:true,
          tabStatus3:false,
          tabStatus4:false
        })
        // code block
        break;
      case 3:
        // code block
        this.setState({

          tabStatus1:false,
          tabStatus2:false,
          tabStatus3:true,
          tabStatus4:false
        })
        break;
      case 4:
        this.setState({

          tabStatus1:false,
          tabStatus2:false,
          tabStatus3:false,
          tabStatus4:true
        })
        // code block
        break;

    }
  }




  render() {
    return ( 
      <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
       <Container>
        <Header />
        <Content />
        <Footer>
          <FooterTab>
            <Button  onPress={()=>{this.checkTabSelected(1)}} active={this.state.tabStatus1} style={{backgroundColor: this.state.tabStatus1?'red':null}} >
              <Text>Apps</Text>
            </Button>
            <Button  onPress={()=>{this.checkTabSelected(2)}} active={this.state.tabStatus2}  style={{backgroundColor: this.state.tabStatus2?'red':null}}>
              <Text>Camera</Text>
            </Button>
            <Button onPress={()=>{this.checkTabSelected(3)}} active={this.state.tabStatus3}  style={{backgroundColor: this.state.tabStatus3?'red':null}}>
              <Text>Navigate</Text>
            </Button>
            <Button  onPress={()=>{this.checkTabSelected(4)}} active={this.state.tabStatus4}  style={{backgroundColor: this.state.tabStatus4?'red':null}}>  
              <Text>Contact</Text>
            </Button>
          </FooterTab>
        </Footer>
      </Container>
      </View>
    );
  }
} 

const styles = StyleSheet.create({




});
```

Comment: but onPress even of mine I am also navigating to other screen

Comment: Didn't get you....dou u want to say that on press you are loading another screen but u still have the footer ?

Comment: done that! thanks...accepting ur answer btw..It was right too

Answer (score 1):

I gave detailed information on this subject

```
"react-native": "0.62.2",

"native-base": "^2.13.12"

"@react-navigation/drawer": "^5.8.2",

"@react-navigation/native": "^5.5.1",

"@react-navigation/stack": "^5.5.1",
```

=> https://stackoverflow.com/a/62372156/11302100