# Native Base Tabs Bar styling

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6, react-native, native-base

Any solution for styling the  bar container in Native base ?

The offered vars are not enough, Like I need to change TabsContainer height, remove the bottom border and do some side padding before the tabs

Before I ask I checked all the related topics and nothing suitable for my situation

```
    import React, { Component } from 'react';

    import { Container, Tab, Tabs, ScrollableTab, Icon, Text } from 'native-base';

    import Tab1 from './tabOne';
    import Tab2 from './tabTwo';
    import Tab3 from './tabThree';
    import Tab4 from './tabFour';
    import Tab5 from './tabFive';

    export default class ProdList extends Component {
      render() {
        return (
          <Container>
            <Tabs tabContainerStyle={{ height: 30, borderWidth: 0 }} tabBarUnderlineStyle = {{ width: 0, borderWidth: 0}} tabBarBackgroundColor='#fff' tabStyle={{backgroundColor: '#fff'}}   renderTabBar={()=> <ScrollableTab />}>
            
              <Tab tabStyle={{backgroundColor: '#fff',marginLeft: 30, marginRight: 30, paddingLeft: 30  }} textStyle={{fontFamily: 'Poppins', color: '#aeaeb1'}} activeTabStyle={{ height: 30,backgroundColor: '#fbeaee',borderRadius: 20,marginTop: 10,}} activeTextStyle={{color: '#333',fontFamily: 'Poppins', fontWeight: 'normal'}} heading="Main Course">
                <Tab1 />
              </Tab>
              
              <Tab   tabStyle={{backgroundColor: '#fff',  }} textStyle={{color: '#aeaeb1',fontFamily: 'Poppins', }} activeTabStyle={{ height: 30,backgroundColor: '#fbeaee',borderRadius: 20,marginTop: 10,}} activeTextStyle={{color: '#333',fontFamily: 'Poppins', fontWeight: 'normal'}} heading="Appetizers">
                <Tab2 />
              </Tab>
              
              <Tab   tabStyle={{backgroundColor: '#fff',  }} textStyle={{fontFamily: 'Poppins', color: '#aeaeb1'}} activeTabStyle={{ height: 30,backgroundColor: '#fbeaee',borderRadius: 20,marginTop: 10,}} activeTextStyle={{color: '#333',fontFamily: 'Poppins', fontWeight: 'normal'}} heading="Desserts">
                <Tab3 />
              </Tab>
              
              <Tab   tabStyle={{backgroundColor: '#fff',  }} textStyle={{fontFamily: 'Poppins', color: '#aeaeb1'}} activeTabStyle={{ height: 30,backgroundColor: '#fbeaee',borderRadius: 20,marginTop: 10,}} activeTextStyle={{color: '#333',fontFamily: 'Poppins', fontWeight: 'normal'}} heading="Soups">
                <Tab4 />
              </Tab>
              
              <Tab   tabStyle={{backgroundColor: '#fff',  }} textStyle={{fontFamily: 'Poppins', color: '#aeaeb1'}} activeTabStyle={{ height: 30,backgroundColor: '#fbeaee',borderRadius: 20,marginTop: 10,}} activeTextStyle={{color: '#333',fontFamily: 'Poppins', fontWeight: 'normal'}} heading="Salads">
                <Tab5 />
              </Tab>
              
            </Tabs>
          </Container>
        );
      }
    }
```

**Here is the Result**

[image: This is the result]

need to change TabsContainer height, remove the bottom border and do some side padding before the tabs .. Any solution ?

Comment: Maybe helpful => https://stackoverflow.com/a/62372156/11302100

Comment: @NijatAliyev It may help me with other styling methods, But didn't help with the main issue I am asking .. though thank you